# How do deal with nested InkWell with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Suppose you have a few nested `InkResponse`, if you tap on the inner one, all of the parent will actually trigger the splash effect even though they will loose in the tap arena for the right tapped widget. The effect will be something like this:

[image: example]

How to prevent such behavior? How to display the splash **only** for the tapped widget? In this example image it's being used a `Container` > `Row` (with `InkReponse`) > `Icon` (also with `InkResponse`). This will also happen if you use material buttons.

Comment: Hello, you already found the answer? Please update.

Comment: I created a demo of `InkWell`>`Container`>`Row`>[`Text`, `IconButton`], the ink splash effects are handled separately (i.e. tapping the icon will not trigger the splash of the outer `InkWell`).
May be this is fixed in flutter 2. Can you provide source code?

Comment: Yeah, maybe this is fixed already. It's been a while since this was reported.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try [IgnorePointer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IgnorePointer-class.html)

Answer (score 1):

I encourage you to use **[Stack widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)** because you can be able to put together multiple widgets. Here there is an example of a container with inner container and they are both clickable independently,

```
Stack(
  children: [
    InkWell(
      onTap: (){},
      child: Container(
        width: 400,
        height: 400,
        color: Colors.green,
      ),
    ),
    Positioned(
      top: 30,
      left: 20,
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: (){},
        child: Container(
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ))
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
Center(
            child:Container(
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              child: Card(
                child: InkWell(
                  splashColor: color3,
                  onTap: () {

                  },
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        splashRadius: 7,
                        splashColor: Colors.pink,
                        onPressed: () {},
                        icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                          ImageConst.bellIcon,
                          width: 20,
                          height: 20,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Text("text"),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to wrap the icon into GestureDetector with the empty handler + Padding.

Comment: How do you handle the tap in the icon then?

Comment: You mean GestureDetectory intercepts child clicks? Then I guess you can handle the icon tap in it?

Comment: No, suppose you want to detect the icon tap **only**.

Comment: Figured it out? I hit the same roadblock just now.

Comment: Adding a GestureDetector only removes the second InkResponse, but now the InkResponse on the button expands to fill the entire Card. What we need is some way to allow a nested Material to handle the interaction.